# If the roots of quadratic equation are r and s, what is the value of r-s

Tags: quadratics

Let the roots of quadratic equation $x^2 + px + q$ be equal to $r$ and $s$.

Using Vieta's formulas, what is the value of $r - s$ in terms of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Hint: Can you find $(r-s)^2$ using Vieta formulas?

Comment: oh damn thanks lol

Comment: Alternatively, since the zeroes are given by $$ r , s \ \ = \ \ -\frac{p}{2} \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{p^2 \ -  \ 4q }}{2} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{p}{2} \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{\Delta }}{2}  \ \ , $$ we have $ \ r - s \ = \ \sqrt{\Delta} \ \ , $ a frequently useful "quadratics fact".